# Powershell EWS Managed API Exception on Update

Tags: .net, powershell, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to update some appointments on exchange using EWS managed API, but I keep getting the following error when calling update:

```
Exception: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "Set action is invalid for property." ---> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Set action is invalid 
                    for property.
                       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
                       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalUpdateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId savedItemsDestinationFolderId, ConflictResolutionMode conflictResolution, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 
                    sendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
                       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.UpdateItem(Item item, FolderId savedItemsDestinationFolderId, ConflictResolutionMode conflictResolution, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 
                    sendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode)
                       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalUpdate(FolderId parentFolderId, ConflictResolutionMode conflictResolutionMode, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode)
                       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode conflictResolutionMode)
                       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
                       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                       at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
                       at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                       at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                       at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

This error isn't very descriptive, so I don't really know where to begin. All I am trying to do is change the start and end time of a few appointments. The related code is below:

```
$Items = $service.FindAppointments($Calendar.Id,$CalendarView)
foreach($Item in $Items.Items) {
    $Item.Load()
    $Item.StartTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local
    if ($Item.Subject -eq '01Mar13 15:00 RECD-MTWRF to 30Sep13 17:00'){
        if ($Item.Start.ToString("dddd") -eq 'Friday'){
            $Item.Start = $Item.Start.AddHours(1)
        }
    }
    elseif ($Item.Subject -eq '05Mar13 10:00 RECD-TR to 26Sep13 12:00'){
        if ($Item.Start.ToString("dddd") -eq 'Tuesday'){
            $Item.Start = $Item.Start.AddHours(1)
            $Item.End = $Item.End.AddHours(1)
        }
    }
    try {
        $Item.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AlwaysOverwrite)
    }
    catch {
        $error[0] | fl -force
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the conflict resolution mode and also had to set the Item.StartTimeZone property due to a previous error. Any ideas on what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of `$CalendarView`?

Comment: $CalendarView basically shows the range of calendar to look at, i.e:

    

$CalendarView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView($StartDate,$EndDate)




where startdate and enddate are datetime objects that are already defined.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this and works fine for me:

```
 $Item.Update("AlwaysOverwrite")
```

Comment: may i know why?